# ListView remove column but it is still there

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I use `ListView.Columns.RemoveAt` to remove columns.

The result in the display is correct. According to the display the column has been removed and the removal has been applied to all listview items.

But I also have added a button to transfer the ListView items' text to the clipboard.

The result of the transfer has all the columns - including the removed columns.

Is there maybe some update methods that need to be applied after doing the column removal?

Comment: it's hard for us to determine what's wrong if you do not post relevant code. also, WPF or Winforms? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: How are you setting the data to clipboard?

Comment: I am voting to close this question as **unclear what you're asking** because you're not providing enough info to solve the issue.

Comment: I think the description of the problem is clear and sufficient even without added code and the issue is interesting enough to keep around..

Answer (score 0):

The `Columns` of a `Listview` are only the spots where the `SubItems` are **displayed** not **stored**.

For storage, each `ListVieItem` can have (its own number of) `SubItems`.

When you remove a `Column`, the `SubItems` are untouched.

You would have to **loop** over the `Items` instead and remove, where applicable, the unwanted `SubItems`.

Example 1: Add this to a `Button` and observe how you can press the `Button` as often as you like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Add("ABC");
     Console.WriteLine("Item 0 has " + listView1.Items[0].SubItems.Count + " subitems.);
}
```

Provided you have an `Item[0]` you can add as many `SubItems` as you want, **without** having defined a `Column` where they should be displayed. So they are there but they don't show.

Example 2: Now add another `Button`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int someindex = 4;
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        if (lvi.SubItems.Count - 1 > someindex && lvi.SubItems[someindex] != null)
        {
            lvi.SubItems.RemoveAt(someindex);
            Console.WriteLine("Subitem " + someindex + " removed in Item " + lvi.Index);
        }
}
```

This is how you could remove the `5th SubItem` from each `Item`if there is one..

Comment: aha! Thank You  .. that makes sense.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..